# How to compare two dates that are constructed differently in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to compare two dates, one built with DateTime.parse() and another one build with DateTime(), but so fat I have not been sucessful.

Here is my code snippet.

```
void main(){
  String dateTime = '2020-02-03T08:30:00.000Z';
  int year = 2020;
  int month = 2;
  int day = 3;
  int hour = 8;
  int minute = 30;
  print(DateTime.parse(dateTime).isAtSameMomentAs(DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute)));
}
```

The comparison method returns false, although the dates are supposed to be the same.

What is the correct way of going about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may do that by converting the other date into `utc` and then comparing them with `isAtSameMomentAs` method. working code below:

```
void main(){
  String dateTime = '2020-02-03T08:30:00.000Z';
  int year = 2020;
  int month = 2;
  int day = 3;
  int hour = 8;
  int minute = 30;

  var dt = DateTime.utc(year,month,day,hour,minute);
  print(dt);

  print(DateTime.parse(dateTime).isAtSameMomentAs(dt));

  // 2020-02-03 08:30:00.000Z
  // 2020-02-03 08:30:00.000Z
  // true

}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
void main(){
   String dateTime = '2020-02-03T08:30:00.000Z';
   int year = 2020;
   int month = 2;
   int day = 3;
   int hour = 8;
   int minute = 30;
   print(DateTime.parse(dateTime).isAtSameMomentAs(DateTime.utc(year, month, day, 
   hour, minute)));
}
```

Need to use **DateTime.utc** method for current date time to get accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove 'Z' from your String because when you print the date you can see the difference between two dates is only 'Z'.

If you are getting String from some where else then you can use string methods to remove last 'Z' and then compare it.

It is working fine when you do so.

Comment: You are right sir. Thank you. According to the Dart docs, the isSameomentAs function is time zone agnostic. I assumed the time offset would not affect it.

Comment: The `isAtSameMomentAs` function is time zone agnostic in the sense that it only compares the number of microseconds since epoch. If the two dates are at the same *moment*, even if they are in different time zones and therefore will print as different wall calendar/clock times, then they are equal.